# Get information from stacked notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am working on an android app using api level 19 (4.4 KitKat) that listens for incoming notifications using a subclass of `NotificationListenerService` and then set some flags on the notification based on who the notification is from.

What I am doing currently is getting the `EXTRA_TITLE` from the `extras` Bundle that is part of the notification class and then checking that against values I am storing. This works well enough for when the app that send the notification only has one notification. The problem I am having is if I receive multiple notifications form the same app   (like if I receive sms notifications from two different numbers) the `EXTRA_TITLE` becomes "X new messages."

I have tried using the other members of the `extras` Bundle, but they all post a NullPointerException warning to logcat. How do I get information about stacked notifications?

My `NotificationListenerService` subclass something looks like this:

```
public class Listener extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
       Notification mNotification = sbn.getNotification();

        if(mNotification != null) {

           Bundle extras = mNotification.extras;

           String title = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);

           if(title.equals("criteria")
           {
               mNotification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
           }
    }
}
```